# How do we set up tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

Now that we've got 100 questions (yay!), I've made a round through the tags to see if they could use some cleaning up at this point. I think we'll still have a lot of discussion about tagging to do, but one thing I've noticed is that we already have some rather obvious synonyms.

Now, the tag synonym privileges are a bit weird. For one thing, we don't have any users yet who have enough rep to suggest the synonyms, but they also require a certain score in the relevant tag, which isn't necessarily easy to obtain with the breadth of topics we're currently focussing on.

Would the CMs be able to do some cleaning up at this point or will we just have to wait until we've got sufficiently high-rep users?

For reference, here are a bunch of synonyms I discovered, with the proposed parent tag listed first:

- [performance](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) [efficiency](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efficiency) [optimisation](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimisation) (note also the BE spelling; I remember reading that spelling policy for tags and tag wikis is AE)
- [lighting](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting) [shading](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shading) (I'm happy to be convinced that these are different; if they're not I'm also not sure which one to keep.)
- [pixel-graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-graphics) [pixels](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixels) [pixel-geometry](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-geometry) (The latter might be worth keeping, but I'm not sure about the significance of [pixels](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixels).)
- [color](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color) [color-science](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-science) [color-management](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-management) (Again, the latter might be worth keeping.)
- [stencil-test](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stencil-test) [stencil-buffer](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stencil-buffer)
- [perception](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perception) [human-vision](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-vision)
- [offline](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline) [non-real-time](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-real-time)

We also have duplicate tags on meta. These are largely from the default tags, but some of the cases don't seem to warrant separate tags, so we shouldn't even start fragmenting are tagging landscape. Glaring examples:

- [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic)
- [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging) [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) (The latter two are currently empty.)

I'm sure there are more, if you leave a comment, or [let me know in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26589/computer-graphics) I'm happy to add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't take that long until we can create tag synonyms, even if the CMs don't want to do this. First, tag synonyms can be suggested with 1250 reputation and score of 5+ on the tag, which won't change in public beta. Second when we reach public beta we'll have a few pro-tem moderators who probably can do this, too.

So, as we're aware of these synonym candidates, at the latest, our to-be moderators will be able to set them up.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I'm a pro tem on another site, but I didn't have to handle tag synonyms yet. I can create and approve all synonyms there, regardless of my tag score.